# Where is Python's log function defined?

Tags: python-module

I'm working on a script that imports log from math. I've decided to look inside `math.py` in order to see how `def log` looks like, just for the sake of learning how it's been defined. For my surprise, inside the math.py I couldn't find any log def.
Then I saw scimath.py; there, one can find a `def log(x):`, but it isn't the function I'm importing to my script, since I'm clearly using `from math import log`.

Could anybody help me to understand what's going on there and tell me where can I find `math.log`'s def?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Python math page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#constants), at the bottom, you can see the disclaimer that most Python math functions are just wrappers around C library functions. So, the answer is that it's probably some C source somewhere, depending on which you're using (Cython, Jython, etc), as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476394).